# How to override resourceRequirements with aws_cloudwatch_event_target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I have a AWS Batch Job defined in Terraform and working fine in AWS. I am creating several override rules with `cronExpression()` so the job is invoked at specific times.
I am using `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` and `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`. Most of the functionality works. I am the rule triggers with the right, name, arn, etc. even the right command.
My TF code, simplified, looks like:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "batchjob" {
  name       = "foo"
  is_enabled = true
  # runs on the first of every month at 15:00 UTC 
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html
  schedule_expression = "cron(0 15 1 * ? *)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "batchjob_target" {
  rule     = "foo"
  arn      = "<queue arn>"
  role_arn = "<role arn>"
  input = jsonencode({
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverrides.html
    "ContainerOverrides" : {
      "Command" : [
        "/bin/java",
        "-jar",
        "/batch-jobs.jar",
        "foobar"
      ],
      # VCPU and MEMORY are linked: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_ResourceRequirement.html
      # https://repost.aws/questions/QUP1kkGbDrT1uC4jTW6DXZ4A/set-cpu-and-memory-requirements-for-a-fargate-aws-batch-job-from-an-aws-cloudwatch-event
      "ResourceRequirements" : [
        {
          "Type"  = "VCPU"
          "Value" = "4"
        },
        {
          "Type"  = "MEMORY"
          "Value" = "8192"
        }
      ]
    }
    }
  )
}
batch_target {
  job_name       = "foo"
  job_definition = aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition.arn
}
```

I have confirmed that `ContainerOverrides` and `Command` must be *pascal* case for it work. If I use *camel* case, it doesn't see the overrides.

I was able to get it to work vai the AWS CLI with the following command:

```bash
AWS_PROFILE=dev aws batch submit-job \
        --job-name "foobar" \
        --job-queue "arn:aws:batch:us-west-2:<queue>" \
        --job-definition "arn:aws:batch:us-west-2:<definition>" \
        --container-overrides '{"command": ["/bin/java","-jar","/batch-jobs.jar","foobar"], "resourceRequirements": [{"value": "4", "type": "VCPU"}, {"value": "8192", "type": "MEMORY"}]}'
```

But I cannot figure out the proper syntax, in terraform to override the resource requirements. What am I missing?

Comment: Its not clear what you are doing. What exactly is your `my-batch` module? Where and how do you use `cloudwatch_event_rules` in the module? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for your interest. I did simplify the example I provided. My real world use case is much, much more complicated and part of a large TF repo of which I cannot share much. But I feel pretty confident that the information I provided in this simplified code contains all the relevant parameters that are not working. As for the error, I am not getting any errors. When the event triggers, the `VCPU` and `MEMORY` values are just not used by the container.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is [not supported with EventBridge rule targets](https://repost.aws/questions/QUGiA3Rj8MQwuiK50peypaRg/how-to-override-resourcerequirements-with-aws-cloudwatch-event-target#ANXWu_GyGdSyiD46jII43kYg). We are moving to Scheduler which should allow it.